# Tag exclusion not returning any results

Tags: bug, tags, new-nav, tag-search

[image: Tab screen capture]

I am trying to set up a tab for questions tagged with java, but not android.

If I type `[java] -[android]` into the search bar, I get the list I expect.  but if I type `java not android` into the tag bar, I get this error message.

What am I messing up?

Comment: It works for me. But anyways, I don't think there is "not" keyboard in advanced search. There should only be `-[tag]` -word

Comment: I like the Battleship reference though

Comment: @SteveFest `-[tag]` in the search bar gets formatted to `not tag` in the tag bar. Like in the screenshot

Comment: Every Java question _is_ about Android. /s

Comment: `[java] [is]-[an-answer]`

Comment: @thanksd Oh.. That's right.